# C# 2D arrays calendar day in the month

Tags: c#, arrays, calendar, days

i just need some guidance on how i can display which dates in the month fall on that day. For example, if user enters 0 for monday and 31 days in that month, it will display all the momdays and which date the mondays correspond to in that month? thanks i have this so far but it doesnt seem to work for user input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calendar
{
    class Program
    {
        static int startDay = new int();
        static int totalDays = new int();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the day the first falls on (Mon = 0, etc):    ");
            startDay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("How many days in the month? ");
            totalDays = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    public static List<DateTime> getDates()
    {
        List<DateTime> lstSundays = new List<DateTime>();
        int intMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int intYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int intDaysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(intYear, intMonth);
        DateTime oBeginnngOfThisMonth = new DateTime(intYear, intMonth, 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < intDaysThisMonth + 1; i++)
        {
            if (oBeginnngOfThisMonth.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                lstSundays.Add(new DateTime(intYear, intMonth, i));
            }
        }
        return lstSundays;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post code *as text* rather than as images, and your requirement is too vague for us to help you at the moment. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and bear in mind that the goal of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think that creating a new profile and asking the same question again, with the exact same lack of information that was pointed out to you in the first place, is going to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869698/c-sharp-2d-arrays-calendar-month

Comment: I was about to post the same thing. Add this to your question 'The program should ask you for the day of the week that the first day of the month falls on (numbered between 0 and 6) and how many days there are in the month. It should also ask for the name of the month.' How do you expect help? People cant read your mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calenderMonth1
{
    class Program
    {
    int[][] months;
    int day;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program calendar = new Program();
        calendar.Months();
        calendar.ColRow();
        calender.DisplayMonth();
    }

    public void Display(int itr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i ++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public enum MonthNames
    {
        JANUARY, 
        FEBRUARY, 
        MARCH, 
        APRIL, 
        MAY, 
        JUNE, 
        JULY,
        AUGUST, 
        SEPTEMBER,
        OCTOBER,
        NOVEMBER, 
        DECEMBER
    }
    public void Months()
    {
        int month;
        int[] months = new int[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < months.Count(); i ++)
        {
            month = months[i];
            Console.WriteLine(month + "\t");
        }
    }

    public void ColRow()
    {
        months = new int[12][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i ++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    months[i] = new int[28];    //This may not always be true...  Leap Year every 4 years
                    break;
                case 2:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    months[i] = new int[30];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    months[i] = new int[30];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    months[i] = new int[30];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    months[i] = new int[30];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    months[i] = new int[31];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        int dayInYear = 1;
        for (int thisMonth = 0; thisMonth < months.Count(); thisMonth++)
        {
            for (day = 0; day < months[thisMonth].Count(); day++)
            {
                months[thisMonth][day] = dayInYear;
                dayInYear++;
            }

        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 12; row ++)
        {
            for (int col =0; col < months[row].Count(); col ++)     //Make sure the array doesn't go out of bounds...
            {
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JANUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.FEBRUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MARCH.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.APRIL.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MAY.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JUNE.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JULY.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.AUGUST.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.SEPTEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.OCTOBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.NOVEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.DECEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[row][col] + "\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

void DisplayMonth()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Please insert the numerical value of the month you wish to display:\t");
        int myMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        myMonth -= 1;
        Console.WriteLine();

        switch (myMonth)
        {
            case 0:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JANUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.FEBRUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MARCH.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.APRIL.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MAY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JUNE.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JULY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.AUGUST.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.SEPTEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 9:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.OCTOBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 10:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.NOVEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 11:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.DECEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display the day of the month it is - but rather what day of the year it is..  If you want to display the day of month, switch this:

`//int dayInYear = 1;`
`for (int thisMonth = 0; thisMonth < months.Count(); thisMonth++)`
`{`
    `for (day = 0; day < months[thisMonth].Count(); day++)`
                `{`
                    `months[thisMonth][day] = day;`
                `}`
            `}`

Comment: Mark the checkbox as the answer and vote up on the answers please

Comment: this hasnt got the user input for days in the month? and month name?

Comment: ive done what u said, thanks but just last bit -  
this hasnt got the user input for days in the month? and month name?

Comment: I defined the month names with the `enum`

Comment: And if you only want to display a certain month, based on user input, use the statement I put below

Comment: i replaced it and it doesnt compile

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: I made a new function to cover that.  Hold on a sec

Comment: all i need is the program to ask user input for days in a month and the month name for that and display the calendar for that month, thanks

Comment: i think it just needs a little tweaking

Comment: Then tweak it.  I want to teach you how to fish...  Not do all the fishing for you...

Comment: Edited this one.  Tapping out buddy.  It's all you from here

Answer (score 1):

```
void DisplayMonth()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert the numerical value of the month you wish to display:\t");
    int myMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    myMonth -= 1;
    Console.WriteLine();

    switch (myMonth)
    {
            case 0:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JANUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.FEBRUARY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count(); col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MARCH.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.APRIL.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.MAY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JUNE.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.JULY.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.AUGUST.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.SEPTEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 9:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.OCTOBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 10:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.NOVEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            case 11:
                for (int col = 0; col < months[myMonth].Count()-1; col++)
                    Console.WriteLine(MonthNames.DECEMBER.ToString() + "\t" + months[myMonth][col] + "\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Take a look around the site.  Get your bearings.  It's hard for anyone to help you without seeing your code, and a picture doesn't help.  You can put it right in your question, and it appears as code when you indent it.  You can also put images in your questions - the don't have to be (and shouldn't be) links to images.  Make it easier for yourself to get answers by making it easier for us to give you them.

Comment: Also, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're killin me smalls.

Comment: im sorry but its just too long at the moment and i dont know which bits to delete or repace